# Show stationary distributions for disjoint essential communicating classes are linearly independent (finite state)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, convex-analysis, markov-chains, markov-process

Each essential communicating class $C_1,...,C_k$ (of a finite state MC) has an unique stationary distribution $\pi_{C_l}$ for $1\leq l\leq k$(Levin and Yuval corollary 1.17). We can then define:
\begin{equation*}
\pi_l(i) = \begin{cases}
\pi_{C_l}(i)&\text{if  $i\in C_l$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
for $1\leq l\leq k$

It is clear that each $\pi_l$ is stationary. Is it correct to state that they are linearly independent? If that is not true, would it be correct to state that $\pi_l$ cannot possibly be a convex combination of $\pi_1,...,\pi_{l-1},\pi_{l+1},...,\pi_k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is immediate from the fact that the $C_l$ are disjoint from each other.  So if you have a linear combination $f=\sum a_l\pi_l$ of the $\pi_l$, then for each $i$, $f(i)$ is just $a_l\pi_l(i)$ for the unique $l$ such that $i\in C_l$ (or $0$ if $i$ is not in any $C_l$).  The only way $f$ can be $0$ is thus if $a_l=0$ for all $l$.

Comment: Thank you very much!. Is there an analogous result for infinite state MCs?

Comment: Well, the same exact same reasoning would apply if there were infintiely many states.